# What is stackoverflow.usinfonow.com site

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

I was googling and I found [this site](http://stackoverflow.usinfonow.com/), What is this site?

Comment: Their homepage content is from 5 hours ago, so it may be a scraper. It may also just be a proxy.

Comment: I think I should follow [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/286598)

Comment: I agree, it certainly doesn't hurt to make SE aware of it.

Comment: It also mirrors other sites, such as Reddit: http://reddit.usinfonow.com/ and possibly others. If you go to http://usinfonow.com/ you get a page which says "page not found".